# How to use a water motor in two-way switch for two different electric connection

Tags: electrical

My house is G+2. Each floor is with each brother& its family. All three floor has three separate electric connection of three phase. We have single underground water tank for storage. We have water pump at Ground floor. We need facility to on or off from Ist floor and IInd floor so that as needed families can use water pump to fill the tanks at roof. Kindly provide a solution.

Comment: Does each family have its own separate roof tank? How is the water directed from the one pump to the several roof tanks -- by manual valves? Are all the roof tanks at the same height?

Comment: Is it acceptable for the electricity to fill the tanks to be charged to one family? Can you buy another electric meter?

Comment: no. Tank is common for all. Supply from pump to tank is by single pipe line.  Yet the tanks are different height however there is no problem of filling.

Comment: No, We want the charges of electricity on the basis of use of each family. Means that each family should bear as per his metering.

Comment: There is no problem with Ground floor as he can plug in easily as he needed. He also has separate sockets to start the pump and the load goes to his meter.

Comment: You have not explained how the water from the pump is directed into the roof tank of the family who is pumping.